# QSet append custom Object

Tags: c++, qt, qhash, qset

I have the following class

```
class Test{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

and all that I want is to have a `QSet<Test>` where I will insert some Test objects.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSet<Test> setTest;
    setTest.insert(Test());
    return QCoreApplication::exec();
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error for some reason and I don't know why or how can I fix it.

> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(118): error
> C2665: 'qHash': none of the 24 overloads could convert all the
> argument types C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qlocale.h(62):
> note: could be 'uint qHash(const QLocale &,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qregexp.h(56): note: or
> 'uint qHash(const QRegExp &,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(108): note:
> or       'uint qHash(std::nullptr_t,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(105): note:
> or       'uint qHash(QLatin1String,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(104): note:
> or       'uint qHash(const QBitArray &,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(103): note:
> or       'uint qHash(QStringView,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(101): note:
> or       'uint qHash(const QStringRef &,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(100): note:
> or       'uint qHash(const QString &,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(98): note: or
> 'uint qHash(const QByteArray &,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(97): note: or
> 'uint qHash(const QChar,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(95): note: or
> 'uint qHash(long double,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(93): note: or
> 'uint qHash(double,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(92): note: or
> 'uint qHash(float,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(91): note: or
> 'uint qHash(qint64,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(87): note: or
> 'uint qHash(quint64,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(86): note: or
> 'uint qHash(long,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(80): note: or
> 'uint qHash(ulong,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(79): note: or
> 'uint qHash(int,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(78): note: or
> 'uint qHash(uint,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(77): note: or
> 'uint qHash(short,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(76): note: or
> 'uint qHash(ushort,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(75): note: or
> 'uint qHash(signed char,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(74): note: or
> 'uint qHash(uchar,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(73): note: or
> 'uint qHash(char,uint) noexcept'
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(118): note:
> while trying to match the argument list '(const T)'
> with
> [
> T=Test
> ] C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(117): note:
> see reference to function template instantiation 'uint
> qHash(const T &,uint) noexcept()' being compiled
> with
> [
> Key=Test,
> T=Test
> ] C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhash.h(946): note: while compiling class template member function 'QHashNode<Key,T>
> **QHash<Key,T>::findNode(const Key &,uint *) const'
> with
> [
> Key=Test,
> T=QHashDummyValue
> ] C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhash.h(790): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'QHashNode<Key,T>
> **QHash<Key,T>::findNode(const Key &,uint *) const' being compiled
> with
> [
> Key=Test,
> T=QHashDummyValue
> ] C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhash.h(786): note: while compiling class template member function
> 'QHash<T,QHashDummyValue>::iterator
> QHash<T,QHashDummyValue>::insert(const Key &,const QHashDummyValue &)'
> with
> [
> T=Test,
> Key=Test
> ] C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qset.h(208): note: see reference to function template instantiation
> 'QHash<T,QHashDummyValue>::iterator
> QHash<T,QHashDummyValue>::insert(const Key &,const QHashDummyValue &)'
> being compiled
> with
> [
> T=Test,
> Key=Test
> ] C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qset.h(257): note: see reference to class template instantiation
> 'QHash<T,QHashDummyValue>' being compiled
> with
> [
> T=Test
> ] C:\Users\vlad.dumitru\CLionProjects\Test\main.cpp(11): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'QSet' being
> compiled
> C:\Qt\5.14.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore/qhashfunctions.h(118): error
> C2056: illegal expression NMAKE : fatal error U1077:
> 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2017\BUILDT~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe'
> : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"'
> : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"'
> : return code '0x2' Stop. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"'
> : return code '0x2' Stop.

Does any of you know how can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

```
class Test {
    int a;
    int b;

    bool operator==(const Test &e1) const {
        return e1.a == a && e1.b == b;
    }

    uint qHash(const Test &key, uint seed) {
        return qHash(key.a, seed) ^ key.b;
    }
};
```

I did write those 2 functions that I need but I'm getting a new error now:

> error C2664: 'uint Test::qHash(const Test &,uint)': cannot convert
> argument 1 from 'const int' to 'const Test &'

I cant call the `qHash(key.a, seed)` because "**Reference to type 'const Test' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'const int'**"

Comment: but this is not how it was supposed to be done? I mean its exactly like in this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#qhash

Comment: `class Employee
{
public:
    Employee() {}
    Employee(const QString &name, QDate dateOfBirth);
    ...

private:
    QString myName;
    QDate myDateOfBirth;
};

inline bool operator==(const Employee &e1, const Employee &e2)
{
    return e1.name() == e2.name()
           && e1.dateOfBirth() == e2.dateOfBirth();
}

inline uint qHash(const Employee &key, uint seed)
{
    return qHash(key.name(), seed) ^ key.dateOfBirth().day();
}`

Comment: this is their example, I just followed it 1 to 1. So I'm not quite sure what's wrong over there...

Comment: `qHash()` should not be a member of your class, but be in the same namespace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228850/discussion-between-jack-lilhammers-and-mircea).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QSet` is implemented as a `QHash`, therefore you must implement the `operator==()` in your class and a `qHash()` function in the same namespace of your class.
It'll overload the global `qHash()` and can have one of these signatures

```
uint qHash(K key);
uint qHash(const K &key);

uint qHash(K key, uint seed);
uint qHash(const K &key, uint seed);
```

Qtherwise `QSet` won't be able to hash your data.

You can look at the official example here
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#qhash

---

This is the documentation page about `QSet` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qset.html#details
I'm linking it here for completeness, but it is not clear about this requirement.

Comment: In fact, I don't think it is clearly mentioned. They only specify that `QSet` is a `QHash`